# Reading directory including txt files

Tags: python, parsing

```
def isim():
    fh = open('hash.txt')
    for line in fh:
        if re.search('Unique description', line):
            print(line, end='')
def main():
    isim()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

my question is how can read all text file in a directory instead of hash.txt

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) to list the contents of a directory; you can then add a simple filename filter as needed:

```
path = '/some/directory'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.txt'):
        continue
    filename = os.path.join(path, filename)
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            if re.search('Unique description', line):
                print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the glob module.

```
import re
import glob
def isim():
    textfiles = glob.glob(r"C:\mydir\*.txt")
    for fh in textfiles:
        for line in open(fh):
            if re.search('Unique description', line):
                print(line, end='')
def main():
    isim()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: i use glob.glob but gives me error  NameError: global name 'glob' is not defined                                                  textfiles = glob.glob(r "C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT\Exercise Files\09_Regexes\*.txt")

Comment: @OnurDogu: in Python you have to import modules before you use them.  Your code can only have worked if you had `import re`; here you'd need `import glob` at the top.

Comment: if it works for you, please click the checkbox next to the answer ;) if it doesn't work please let me know. thanks.

Comment: <pre>import re
import glob


class Parse_Txt:
   def Search():
        textfiles = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT\Exercise_Files\09_Regexes\*.txt")
        for fh in textfiles:
             for line in open(fh):
                if re.search('Unique description', line):
                    print(line, end='')

def main():
    f = open('example.csv','w')
    f.write(Parse_Txt.Search())
    f.close()  

if __name__ == "__main__": main()

----------------------------------------------------------
    f.write(Duck.arama())
TypeError: must be str, not None
<pre>

Comment: You need to return a string from your Search function. I pasted code here that should fix the problem: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/22eda0b3fa4c5b971ab1